# Evaluation of $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{\ln n}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k}{k^2+1}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

I want to evaluate
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{\ln n}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k}{k^2+1} $$

I can already see that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{\ln n} = 0$$
so how do we go about solving this?

Comment: mathgrad93, you may want to start learning how to use dollar signs, etc., when posting here.  See http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 3):

We have
$$\sum_{k=1}^n \dfrac1k - \sum_{k=1}^n \dfrac1{k^2} = \sum_{k=1}^n\dfrac{k-1}{k^2}< \sum_{k=1}^n \dfrac{k}{k^2+1} < \sum_{k=1}^n \dfrac{k}{k^2} = \sum_{k=1}^n \dfrac1k$$
Make use of the fact that
$$\sum_{k=1}^n \dfrac1k = \ln(n) + \mathcal{O}(1) \text{ and }\sum_{k=1}^n \dfrac1{k^2} = \mathcal{O}(1)$$
to obtain your desired limit.

Answer (score 2):

$$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{k}{k^2+1}\leq \sum_{k=1}^n\frac{k}{k^2} = \sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k} \leq 1 + \int_1^n\frac{1}{x}dx = 1 + \ln(n) - \ln(1) = 1+\ln(n)$$.

This shows that the limit is at most $1$ since: $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{\ln(n)}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{k}{k^2+1}\leq \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1+\ln(n)}{\ln(n)} = 1$$

You should be able to use a similar argument to show the limit is at least $1$.